# read in raster order?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, raster

hey guys,
i have a c++ programming assignment that asks me to create a matrix and store its elements (given by the user) as an array, read in raster order.  i've looked around for the meaning of "raster order" and i haven't seen anything about it.  any help?  thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_scan#Scan_lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Raster scan order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_scan) means "in order of input/output" - in case of matrix it will mean line-by-line (you could of course store column-by-column instead, but that's not what the assignment asks for).